# Python 3.3: How to create a loop for a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I apologize for the title not being clear, anyways how do I create a loop that will put numbers into a string, what i mean is (this is from the assignment im doing):

Enter number of courses:

Enter grade for course no. **1**:

Enter weight for course no. **1**:

Enter grade for course no. **2**

......

Enter grade for course no. **7**

......

Enter weight for course no. **9**

So how would i do something like this, i have to create an input statement which has numbers in order (1-infinity but limited by number of courses). Thank you if you need anymore information or for me to clarify let me know.

Comment: Sounds like you want a List...

Comment: What is the first piece of information you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string formatting:

```
noc = int(input('Enter number of courses: '))
for i in range(1, noc+1):
    grade = input('Enter grade for course no. {}: '.format(i))
    weight = input('Enter weight for course no. {}: '.format(i))
    #do something with grade and weight here.
```

Comment: when i do something with the grade and weight can i create a variable gpa which would be the answer to (grade/weight)??? If so would it repeat it "i" times?

Comment: @TalatZaitoun Yes you can do: `gpa = grade/float(weight)`, and this would be repeated `i` times. Note that I used `float()` because in case both grade and weight are integers then you'll get a truncated output and don't forget to convert `grade` and `weight` to numbers as well because `input()` returns a string.

Comment: I'm so sorry i got confused (everything u said worked for me, thank u), I'm actually supposed to print the gpa at the end and its supposed to take all the inputted numbers and add them and then divide them (grade/weight) what i mean is (grade 1 + grade 2 + so on /weight 1 + weight 2 + so on)

Comment: i was able to get it to work, thank you hcwhsa